# Ticket sales through expression engine?

Tags: expresso-store, ecommerce

Does anyone have any experience with selling tickets box office style? I have exp:resso store, but I havent seen addy add ons for ticket sales. In a perfect world, it would be awesome for the customer should be able to buy the ticket and then print a ticket after payment.

Does anyone have any suggestions or advice?

Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

I have created several sites that sell tickets to classes and the like, using Exp:resso Store. It should work fine for what you want. You would want to add each event as a "product", and you could use the product modifiers for different ticket levels if necessary (orchestra vs. balcony, etc.). If you set the modifier to use multiple SKUs you can accommodate differing numbers of tickets at each level.

For printing tickets, you would want to set up a member account page (you could use Freemember or Zoo Visitor to make this process much easier) that lists all of a person's orders using the {exp:store:orders member_id="CURRENT_USER"} tag pair. You will link from there to a new template that uses something like the following (assuming your link was constructed like: `{path="account/orders/{order_hash}/{entry_id}"}`) to get information about the event they registered for:

```
{exp:store:orders order_hash="{segment_3}"}
  {items}{if entry_id == {segment_4}}
    {!-- Whatever information you want to display on your ticket --}
  {/if}{/items}
{/exp:store:orders}
```

Of course, you could also link to that same template from the order confirmation page.

Comment: You can use any of the tags from https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/checkout_tag.html here to show the event details for each product as Eli has mentioned. Also depending on the Venue you might want/need to use something along the lines of ( http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-qr-code ) to create QR Codes for venues that have scanners.

Comment: Is there a way to add a unique number name to the ticket that was bought? For example, if someone buys ten tickets how can I keep track of each individual ticket?

Comment: You can store the name as a custom modifier field. If you need the actual person's name for each ticket (rather than one name of the person who bought them), you could probably use the {exp:store:product_form} tag plus some javascript to duplicate the product markup on the page. So instead of adding a quantity of 5 to your cart, you would be adding the same event five different times (in one form submission), each having a different "name" modifier field.

Comment: @ee_doug could I ask how this project worked out for you as we have very similar requirements.